# Put JLabels and JTextField in same frame as JTable

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield, layout-manager

I am trying to put some text fields and labels underneath a `JTable` or a similar `GridLayout`.

When I type data in the fields, I want to pass them on to the table.  I now have text fields and labels within a panel, but want to add a table above.

I tried using `JPanel`, `JFrame`, `JTable`. But I could not get them working together.

What are the experiences with Swing/AWT imports, any suggestions about the best way to get this result?

Comment: People commonly use [combinations of layout managers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) to achieve complex layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could easily be accomplished with a `BorderLayout`. Add the `JLabel` and the `JTextField` to a `JPanel` with its default `FlowLayout` and add the `JPanel` and the `JTabel` to the frame using proper `BorderLayout` position

Something like this

```
    JTable table = new JTable(data, cols);
    JTextField jtf = new JTextField(20);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("This is a text field");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(jtf);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);                     <----
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);   <----
```

Rum this example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TableWithOthers {

    public TableWithOthers() {

        Object[][] data
                = {{"Hello", "World"},
                {"Hello", "World"},
                {"Hello", "World"},
                {"Hello", "World"}};
        String[] cols = {"Hello", "World"};

        JTable table = new JTable(data, cols);
        JTextField jtf = new JTextField(20);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("This is a text field");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(jtf);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TableWithOthers();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

For adding the rows dynamically, you could just use the basic `DefaultTableModel`. If you know your column names you could do something like this

```
String[] cols = {"Col 1, "Col 2", "Col 3};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(cols, 0);
JTable table = new JTabel(model);
```

Then to add the row, just do somethind like this in a button `actionPerformed` method

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String data1 = textField1.getTex();
    String data2 = textField2.getTex();
    String data3 = textField3.getTex();

    Object[] row = {dat1, data2, data3};
    model.addRow(row);
}
```

Just adding rows to the model with update your table dynamically

Comment: thanks a lot! I used parts of this code to pass all the fields and labels to my own project. I have exactly what I wanted now.

Answer (score 4):

### You could....

Use a `BorderLayout`, leaving the `JTable` (wrapped in a `JScrollPane`) in the `NORTH` position.

Add a `JPanel`, containing the `JLabel` and `JTextField`, using a `FlowLayout` or `GridBagLayout` to the `SOUTH` position

### You could...

Use a `GridBagLayout`, adding all the components to a single panel...

You should take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details...

Comment: It is a pretty simple project, it should be as simple as possible. If I fill in the fields I want to add a row to the table with the data and calculate some things. will a GridBagLayout be a good solution for this?

Comment: Adding data to the table is irrelevant, but yes, GridBagLayout can allow you to add the table above the two fields...